# How to get all the actions related to a Azure LogicApp run by Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that has more than 100 actions. I am using following code to get all the actions and status for a logic app run,

```
        return _client
            .WorkflowRunActions
            .ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(_resourceGroup, logicApp, workflowRunName)
            .Result.Body.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime);
```

But it only returns 30, not all actions. In my logic app, I have some actions to insert a record to Azure Sql tables, for instance,
[image]

But those actions were not returned by above code. Also I noticed all the actions under conditions were not returned either. Can anyone share some thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Result Body, there is a `NextPageLink` property, it's used to get the next response page. You could refer to my below code.

```
            Task<AzureOperationResponse<IPage<WorkflowRunAction>>> actions = client.WorkflowRunActions.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName: "resource group name", workflowName: "gelogic", runName: "run name");

            var nextaction = client.WorkflowRunActions.ListNextWithHttpMessagesAsync(actions.Result.Body.NextPageLink);

            var numerator = nextaction.Result.Body.GetEnumerator();

            while (numerator.MoveNext()) {
                WorkflowRunAction item = numerator.Current;
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think my code returns the first page actions, which is 30.